# Update attribute on check box click (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

I've been searching forever to find an actual answer to this:

What would be the best way to update an object's attribute via ajax when a checkbox is clicked? It's simply a matter of wanting to flip an attribute from false to true and vice versa.

There are one or two threads on stackoverflow about this, but they either employ observe_field (I'd rather just do it with a Prototype function) or have never solved the problem at all, it seems.

Again, this is Rails 3 and Prototype.

Comment: `observe_field` is a Ruby helper that generates a Prototype function... why wouldn't you want to use it?

Comment: @Sean it seems that observe_field is depreciated according to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field

Comment: @Dty: Ah, that's a good reason not to use it then... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's the checkbox part that's tripping you up?

All you really need to do is have a method in your model to toggle the appropriate field

```
# somewhere in your model
my_boolean_field.toggle
```

and then bind a `.click()` handler to your checkbox to do an ajax request. If you need to, in the `.click()` handlers callback you can update the checkbox but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

The only part that's tricky here is what to do if the user clicks the checkbox quickly several times. One option is to disable the checkbox after it's clicked until the callback finishes.

Comment: I guess what was tripping me up was the the way that Rails will expect that data to be formatted, and into what controller. I was thinking I'd have to send it to the Update controller somehow, but maybe it's best if I build a specific controller just for this action.

Comment: Update is an **action** in your controller. Usually, you'll have a controller that corresponds to a model. For example, if you have a model called "book" you might have a "BooksController". And that "BooksController" will have actions such as "show, update, create" etc. And yes, you are right that you should create a new **action** to toggle your attribute.

Comment: Sorry - that's what I meant: the Update action in TasksController